Dask-distributed LocalCluster spinup hangs only in non-interactive execution
I want to start and connect to a dask.distributed LocalCluster from within a python script. However, I get different behavior depending on the way in which I invoke the same lines of code. The following works as expected when run from within a cell in a jupyter notebook:
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)
from time import sleep
sleep(5)

The output it produces is what I would expect; there is one line with the scheduler's address, and ~12 pairs of lines corresponding to the ~12 workers that it starts. It also finishes execution a few seconds after it finishes writing output, as exepected. I also get this
same expected behavior from running all of these commands by passing a string to the python executable, i.e. at the commandline running python -c "from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster; cluster = LocalCluster(); client = Client(cluster); from time import sleep; sleep(5)". However, when I run the exact same lines of code but by putting them in a file and invoking python file_containing_above_code.py, I get dozens of different versions of the following all trying to write to stdout at the same time:
  Scheduler at:     tcp://127.0.0.1:44911
  dashboard at:  http://127.0.0.1:45103/status

Each one has a different scheduler and dashboard address, which leads me to believe it is spinning up many clusters for some reason. It also hangs indefinitely at this point. I suspect I can circumvent this for now by cating the script and piping it to python -c, but for hopefully obvious reasons I would prefer to be able to run the script without having to do this. Is this a known behavior of dask?

No, it is not, could you print the entire stdout logs? I see no reason this would spawn several Dask Schedulers.
